# login an application according roles of an entity

Tags: symfony-2.3

I have a User class with roles (ROLE_ADMIN, ...) and a Class Group, the relationship between them is:
Group(OneToMany) ------ User(ManyToOne).
I remove the attribute "role" of the User class to put in the Group class, so the Group class contains the roles

when I create a user on my form

> (the form contains a chexbox derive the group class with different roles, and at the database everything is normal, group_id is in the User table)

and I'm trying to connect me with this user I get an error:

> "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument Passed 4 to Symfony \ Component \ Security \ Core \ Authentication \ Token ..."

How do I connect according the identifier of the entity Group (group_id) because group_id match a unique role?

Thank you in advance.(Excuse my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should create in your user entity method getRoles which return all your roles based on your assignment to groups
something like that:

```
public function getRoles()
{
     $roles = array();
     foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
           foreach($group->getRoles() as $role)
                  $roles[] = $role;
     }
     return $roles;
}
```

Your User Entity muest return array of User's roles - interface required it

Comment: Why u itereate through $group->getRoles(), create and return the same array?